# Insert rows from one table to columns of another table with specific pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following table

[image]

I need to transform above data to another table in following format

[image]

Also source table will have varying number of TypeOfContact, thus I need a target table with dynamically generated column names.
I am literally clueless about how to write a sql query to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #temp 
  ( 
     requestid     INT, 
     primaryname1  VARCHAR(50), 
     primaryemail1 VARCHAR(50), 
     sitename1     VARCHAR(50), 
     siteemail1    VARCHAR(50) 
  ) 

SELECT * 
INTO   #row 
FROM   (SELECT m.*, 
               Row_number() 
                 OVER( 
                   partition BY requestid, typeofcontact 
                   ORDER BY typeofcontact) rn 
        FROM   <your_table> m) m 

DECLARE @max_row     INT, 
        @current_row VARCHAR(5) = '1', 
        @SQL         VARCHAR(max) = '', 
        @alter_SQL   VARCHAR(max) = ''; 

SELECT @max_row = Max(rn) 
FROM   #row; 

WHILE @current_row <= @max_row 
  BEGIN 
      IF @current_row <> '1' 
        BEGIN 
            SET @alter_SQL = 'ALTER TABLE #temp add primaryname' 
                             + @current_row + ' varchar(50), primaryemail' 
                             + @current_row + ' varchar(50), sitename' + @current_row 
                             + ' varchar(50), siteemail' + @current_row 
                             + ' varchar(50)' 

            EXEC(@alter_SQL) 
        END 

      SET @SQL = @SQL + ',MAX(CASE WHEN rn=' + @current_row 
                 + ' and TypeOfContact = ''Primary''  THEN ContactName END) "a' 
                 + @current_row + '" ,MAX(CASE WHEN rn=' 
                 + @current_row 
                 + ' and TypeOfContact = ''Primary''  THEN ContactEmail END)    "b' 
                 + @current_row + '" ,MAX(CASE WHEN rn=' 
                 + @current_row 
                 + ' and TypeOfContact = ''Site''  THEN ContactName END)    "c' 
                 + @current_row + '" ,MAX(CASE WHEN rn=' 
                 + @current_row 
                 + ' and TypeOfContact = ''Site''  THEN ContactEmail END)   "d' 
                 + @current_row + '"' 
      SET @current_row = Cast(( Cast(@current_row AS INT) + 1 ) AS INT) 
  END 

SET @SQL = 'insert into #temp SELECT requestid' + @SQL 
           + 'FROM #row group by RequestId'

EXEC(@SQL) 

SELECT * 
FROM   cust 

SELECT * 
FROM   #temp
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use pivoting logic along with `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RequestId, TypeOfContact
                                 ORDER BY ContactEmail) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    RequestId,
    MAX(CASE WHEN TypeOfContact = 'Site' AND rn = 1
             THEN ContactName) AS SiteName1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN TypeOfContact = 'Site' AND rn = 1
             THEN ContactEmail) AS SiteEmail1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN TypeOfContact = 'Site' AND rn = 2
             THEN ContactName) AS SiteName2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN TypeOfContact = 'Site' AND rn = 2
             THEN ContactEmail) AS SiteEmail2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN TypeOfContact = 'Site' AND rn = 3
             THEN ContactName) AS SiteName3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN TypeOfContact = 'Site' AND rn = 3
             THEN ContactEmail) AS SiteEmail3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN TypeOfContact = 'Primary' AND rn = 1
             THEN ContactName) AS PrimaryName1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN TypeOfContact = 'Primary' AND rn = 1
             THEN ContactEmail) AS PrimaryEmail1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN TypeOfContact = 'Primary' AND rn = 2
             THEN ContactName) AS PrimaryName2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN TypeOfContact = 'Primary' AND rn = 2
             THEN ContactEmail) AS PrimaryEmail2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN TypeOfContact = 'Primary' AND rn = 3
             THEN ContactName) AS PrimaryName3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN TypeOfContact = 'Primary' AND rn = 3
             THEN ContactEmail) AS PrimaryEmail3
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    RequestId;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would like to know if there is any way to dynamically generate the query with respect to the input table as the result set of input table will be varying.

Comment: Yes you can use dynamic SQL, to build the exact pivot query with the right number of columns.  But I don't know the syntax offhand.

Comment: This query is giving me correct out put  but I somehow need the dynamic version which I am not able to figure out.